# Stability of A Driven Pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, oscillators, stability

I am having confusion with regards to the proof of my problem. This involves a pendulum with harmonically driven pivot and the task is to show that the pendulum is stable in the inverted position when the amplitude of the driving acceleration is sufficiently high. For reference, consider the problem below.

> Consider a pendulum with harmonically driven pivot. The equation of motion is
> $$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}=-\frac{g+a_d(t)}{L}\sin\theta$$
> where $a_d(t)=A_0\sin(2\pi t/T_d)$ is the time-varying acceleration of the pivot. Show that when the amplitude of the driving acceleration is sufficiently high ($A_0\gg g$), the pendulum is stable in the inverted position (i.e., if $\theta(t=0)\approx180°$).

I understand that when $A_0 \gg g$, the $g$ term in the equation of motion can be dropped. But how can I show that the pendulum is stable for such case?

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: @Jonas Thank you for doing the amendments. Will learn this in no time to seek help on this forum. Appreciated!

Comment: I'm having a problem visualizing an inverted pendulum in equilibrium.  I can balance a plunger with the end of the handle on my palm and the heavy end at the top.  Are you talking about a 2D equivalent of this?

Comment: It probably should look like that in the first place.

Comment: @R.W.Bird The problem above has an element of consistency on this paper. Maybe it was meant to oscillate in a vertical manner. Here is a link to the paper [link](https://backend.orbit.dtu.dk/ws/portalfiles/portal/3722985/Gr%C3%B8nbech.pdf)

Comment: In the link provided, the pivot point is driven up and down (vertically).